# papparse how do I manage errors and retrieve meta information while pipeling?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, papaparse

I am parsing a CSV file using papparse streaming feature

```js
    import fs from 'node:fs'
    import papa from "papaparse"
    const reader = fs.createReadStream(csvPath)
        .pipe(something)
        .pipe(papa.parse(papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {
            skipEmptyLines: true
        }))
        .pipe(somethingelse)
```

- How can I manage parsing errors?
- How can I retrieve auto-detected `linebreak` and `delimiter` properties of `meta` object?

Thanks